# crystalreports only working localhost not ip on iis

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

I publish one website containing Crystal reports on IIS 7.5
if I open it using `http://localhost:8081/` it's showing the report in the reportviewer but if I use my IP adress instead of localhost like `http://ip:8081/` the website work but when click show report not showing anything? Any soloution???

Comment: They are the same environment with the same configurations?

Comment: yes this ip is for localhost

Comment: To load the .RPT file need you to be logged in doing some authentication?

Comment: I re install crystal report in the machine and it's working now.